# An equivalent to is_array() in Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is there a way to test whether something is an array or not in Liquid? Or if an array is empty? Or if a variable is defined but empty?

I'm trying to write something for Shopify that will only show a particular metafield if the product doesn't have any variants, but there doesn't seem to be any way of testing if `product.variants` has any content in Liquid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can use `.size` to check the length of a string or the size of an array. For example, `if product.variants.size > 1`.

Read about [Array Filters in Liquid](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#size).

Comment: Don't forget you probably want `if product.variants.size > 0` or `if product.variants.size >= 1`. Otherwise, the array would need at least 2 items for that condition to pass.

Comment: @SteveEdson Yep, but that's not a mistake. In Shopify it's impossible for `product.variants` to have 0 entries. The minimum is always 1, so in this instance it's correct.

Comment: Apologies, didn't realise that.

Comment: @SteveEdson No worries! 99% of the time you would have been correct!